# How to create a <a-sky></a-sky> image with zoom?

Tags: html, aframe

i am newbie in a-frame , and i have a simple question(actually it's hard for me)

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.5.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<a-scene>
    <a-assets>
     <img id="sky" src="http://aprinweb.ir/vr/img/monument.jpg">
    </a-assets>
    <!-- <a-light type="spot" color="#ff0000" position="0.13 1.31 -1.18" look-at="a-box"></a-light> -->
    <a-sky src="#sky"></a-sky>
</a-scene>
```

http://aprinweb.ir/vr/

i build this sample last night , i need to insert zoom for this a-sky tag (because i need to create a vr like virtual tour)
how can create zoom on aframe to zoom on a picture???
thanks for your help

Comment: Would it be enough to position the `<a-sky>` element closer to the camera, and reduce the radius of `<a-sky>` to make it more apparent?

Comment: no,I have not used the camera ...
I do not know how to use the camera  , I have to use camera?
can you Explain a little bit with example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latest aframe (v0.9.0) has already supported this feature. You would need to use a camera tag by adding following to your `<a-scene>` tag.

```
<a-entity camera look-controls position="0 1.6 0" id="camera-id"></a-entity>
```

The newly added camera will be used instead of the system default one. In you code, do something similar to this:

```
var camera = document.querySelector('#camera-id');
camera.setAttribute('camera', 'zoom', your_zoom_factor);
```

Please see https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/docs/components/camera.md for more details and examples.